# Zend date is singleton?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following code:

```
$fromDate = new Zend_Date();
$this->view->fromDate = $fromDate->getIso();
$this->mongoFromDate = new MongoDate($fromDate->getTimeStamp());

$toDate = new Zend_Date();
$toDate->setDay(3);
$this->view->toDate = $toDate->getIso();
$this->mongoToDate = new MongoDate($toDate->getTimeStamp());
```

Which for some reason is setting the $this->view->toDate and $this->view->fromDate values to the same value. Any thoughts on what could cause this? I'm completely stumped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried this, more basic code:

```
<?php
include("Zend/Date.php");

$fromDate = new Zend_Date();
echo $fromDate->getIso();

echo "<br />";

$toDate = new Zend_Date();
$toDate->setDay(3);
echo $toDate->getIso();
```

And I get the expected result:

```
2012-01-31T22:22:30+00:00
2012-01-03T22:22:30+00:00
```

So either (a) your Zend_Date is oddly broken, which seems fairly unlikely, (b) your view code isn't doing what you think it's doing, or (c) it's the third of the month where you are at the moment :D

Comment: I'm going to bet option b is the solution. I was hoping to be informed of some known bug in Zend :( Time to read more documentation and see what that view code is doing exactly.